# Vector Tiles - Geometry render issue (MBTiles)

Tags: geoserver, wms

I'm having some issues regarding rendering vector tiles in GeoServer.

In the first image below, the server is rendering an image/png with parks in red.
In the second image below, the server is also rendering a pbf (application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile) with the parks in red.

The issue is in the second image, the geometry does not look good. I should be getting the same visual on both cases right?

Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

-- UPDATE

In black it's easier to understand the issue, we can see a black rectangle on the left side of the image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you explain what doesn't look right to you? Other than one being zoomed in more than the other they look pretty much identical to me

Comment: you can almost see squares on the second image the layers are overlapping (in red)

Comment: @IanTurton can you have a look now? Interesting on the third image with a different datastore it's visible a grid line on top of the parks layer. What is going on :D

Comment: I have no idea on how the vector tiles works so I can't help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is the problem here, but sometimes issues with vector geometries from GeoServer appear when a layer contains simple **and** multi geometries. If GeoServer reads a layer as one containing single geometries it interprets multi geometries not correctly and displays them not the way we expect. Example of solution:when using layer from database store and defining layer SQL view,  it's "safer" to force multi geometry type. If other type of store is used I recommend cleaning data input.
In general - I advice checking geometry types.